# Implementing Swiper in Angular 8

Tags: angular, npm, swiper.js

I am trying to implement **Swiper** in my Angular 8 application: https://swiperjs.com/get-started/.

I have created a javascript file in my assets folder and included it into my `angular.json`.

Also I have included **Swiper** in my `app.module.ts` and ran the command
`npm install @types/swiper`.

**However, I get the error:**

`[ts] Module '"../node_modules/@types/swiper/index has no exported member 'Swiper'`

when it clearly does. I am not sure where I am going wrong.

**card-swipe.component.ts**

```
import { SwiperModule, SwiperConfigInterface } from 'ngx-swiper-wrapper';



@Component({
  selector: 'app-card-swipe',
  templateUrl: './card-swipe.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./card-swipe.component.css']
})
export class CardSwipeComponent implements OnInit {


constructor() { }
something;
index;
config: SwiperConfigInterface = {
  a11y: true,
  direction: 'horizontal',
  slidesPerView: 3,
  slideToClickedSlide: true,
  mousewheel: true,
  scrollbar: false,
  watchSlidesProgress: true,
  navigation: true,
  keyboard: true,
  pagination: false,
  centeredSlides: true,
  loop: true,
  roundLengths: true,
  slidesOffsetBefore: 100,
  slidesOffsetAfter: 100,
  spaceBetween: 50,
  breakpoints: {
      // when window width is >= 320px
      320: {
          slidesPerView: 1
      }
  }
};

ngOnInit() {}

}
```

**card-swipe.component.html**

```
<p>Hi this works</p>
<!-- Slider main container -->
<swiper fxFlex="auto" [config]="config" (indexChange)="onIndexChange($event)">
    <div *ngFor="let step of something; let index = index" class="swiper-slide cursor-pointer">
        <div fxLayout="column" fxLayoutAlign="center center" fxFlexFill class="mx-2">
          <p>hi</p>
          <h1>hello</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
</swiper>
```

Comment: have you seen https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-swiper-wrapper ?

Comment: See if this is related to this topic, check on this link [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65803859/5471331)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We're using Swiper in our Angular application.

How we integrated it:
There's an npm package specificatlly for Angular: 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-swiper-wrapper

So you basically just have to install the package:

`npm i ngx-swiper-wrapper`

Then, import the module (we've put that into our `SharedModule` and exported it, so that it's accessable from everywhere:

```
imports: [
    // more imports here
    SwiperModule
]
```

and then you can use it in your components like this:

```
<swiper fxFlex="auto" [config]="config" (indexChange)="onIndexChange($event)">
    <div *ngFor="let step of something; let index = index" class="swiper-slide cursor-pointer">
        <div fxLayout="column" fxLayoutAlign="center center" fxFlexFill class="mx-2">
            <!-- Your content goes here -->
        </div>
    </div>
</swiper>
```

As a config you can have something like this:

```
    config: SwiperConfigInterface = {
        a11y: true,
        direction: 'horizontal',
        slidesPerView: 3,
        slideToClickedSlide: true,
        mousewheel: true,
        scrollbar: false,
        watchSlidesProgress: true,
        navigation: true,
        keyboard: true,
        pagination: false,
        centeredSlides: true,
        loop: true,
        roundLengths: true,
        slidesOffsetBefore: 100,
        slidesOffsetAfter: 100,
        spaceBetween: 50,
        breakpoints: {
            // when window width is >= 320px
            320: {
                slidesPerView: 1
            }
        }
    };
```

No need to include any styles in your `angular.json` file. They all come with that module you imported.

Comment: It wont work because it cannot load an image `Error while trying to use the following icon from the Manifest: http://localhost:4200/assets/icons/icon-144x144.png (Download error or resource isn't a valid image)`

Comment: Are you sure that this error comes from the swiper implementation? I just checked my project and cannot find any image which is called like that.

Comment: Yeah I am not sure why I got that error... I still have a blank screen but I am debugging rn

Comment: What is your dev console saying? Your screen cannot be blank because of this image error.

Comment: I get no error from the console... and it’s not the whole screen just the code within the `<swiper>`

Comment: Ah okey. Did you define some swiper config? I will update my answer to provide you with some default config

Comment: I imported **SwiperConfigInterface** from `ngx-swiper-wrapper` and incleded the configuration... but I still get no error from the console

Comment: Can you please post some more code in your thread? I need the HTML and the ts (only the relevant pieces) part to further debug.

Comment: Please doublecheck if all your variables are defined. I would assume that ```something``` is not defined for you in the ```*ngFor``` loop insider your ```<swiper>``` tag. You might want to set up your IDE so it warns you from not defined variables

Comment: Sorry I still get the same error... do I need to define a `onIndexChange($event)` method as well?

Comment: Well if you have it in your template, yes. If you don't need it, just delete this part: ```(indexChange)="onIndexChange($event)"```

Comment: How do access to the directive methods?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: I am facing the error for angular 8
An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.

Comment: I am attempting to implement the Swiper library in my Angular app through its CDN but it been unsucessful. I was hoping you could help me out here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61021368/how-to-use-swiperjs-cdn-in-angular

Comment: Worked for me at first even with Angular 10 even when it show a warning saying it required Angular 9.