# How to use Swiperjs CDN in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, cdn, swiper.js

I understand there is a module, but I would like to use Swiper js in my angular app through its CDN.

I have included the scripts in `head` of my `index.html`.

Then in the component where I want to use it, I have delared it as such:

```js
  import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { MenuService } from '../_services/menu.service';
import { ContentfulService } from '../_services/contentful.service';
import { Entry } from 'contentful';
declare let Swiper: any;

/* and initialised in the constructor*/

  constructor(
    public menu: MenuService,
    private contentfulService: ContentfulService
  ) {
    new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
      // Optional parameters
      direction: 'vertical',
      loop: true,
    });
  }
```

I am not getting any errors, but it simply will not work. The arrows for instance are also loaded but there is no event bound to them. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Can u create stackblitz example ?

Comment: @Çağrı Here it is: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-v4cunb

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change your script and css link in index.html https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-d21ywf

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/3.4.2/css/swiper.min.css">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/3.4.2/js/swiper.min.js"></script>
```

and take your swiper to afterinit

```
import { Component ,AfterViewInit} from '@angular/core';
declare let Swiper: any;


@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  implements AfterViewInit {
  name = 'Angular';

  constructor() {

  }
  ngAfterViewInit() {
    new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
       pagination: '.swiper-pagination',
        paginationClickable: true,
        nextButton: '.swiper-button-next',
        prevButton: '.swiper-button-prev',
        autoplay: 3000,
        spaceBetween: 30,
        direction: 'vertical',
        loop: true
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Perfect thank you! What was wrong with my script and css link that I included? I got those from the official site!

Comment: Next time I want to use a library only though its CDN, what do I look out for to copy the correct link for scripts and css?

Comment: Por que es necesario colocar esta línea; ```declare let Swiper: any;```