# Why is Swiper not working for me in angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, swiper.js

I am trying to use Swiper but I cannot achieve it, I followed the steps in the documentation (https://swiperjs.com/get-started/), the problem is that
all the images / slides are mixed together, it allows me to slide to the side but since all the images are together it does not work. It shows me a slide with all the content, which I can
slide but it has nothing on the sides. I'm doing it in ngOnlnit, at first not even the swiped worked correctly, but when I added setTimeout to delay the creation of var swiper it started to work (the swiped only)

component.ts:

```
import 'swiper/swiper-bundle.css';
import Swiper, { Navigation, Pagination } from 'swiper';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-sing-accesorios',
  templateUrl: './sing-accesorios.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./sing-accesorios.component.css']
})
export class SingAccesoriosComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(){

    Swiper.use([Navigation, Pagination]);

  }

  ngOnInit(): void {

    setTimeout(function(){
        var swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container');
    },500)

  }
}
```

component.html:

```
  <!-- Swiper -->
  <div class="swiper-container">
    <div class="swiper-wrapper">
      <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 1</div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 2</div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 3</div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 4</div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 5</div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 6</div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 7</div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 8</div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 9</div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 10</div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

component.css:

```
.swiper-container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
}

.swiper-slide {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 18px;
  background: #fff;

  /* Center slide text vertically */
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
  justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

Comment: Please use this package for swiper: https://stackblitz.com/github/zefoy/ngx-swiper-wrapper/tree/master?file=projects%2Fapp%2Fsrc%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Refer to this documentation [Swiper Angular](https://swiperjs.com/angular/)

on HTML - your.component.html

```
<swiper [slidesPerView]="3" [spaceBetween]="50" (swiper)="onSwiper($event)" (slideChange)="onSlideChange()" #newSwiper>
  <ng-template swiperSlide>Slide 1</ng-template>
  <ng-template swiperSlide>Slide 2</ng-template>
  <ng-template swiperSlide>Slide 3</ng-template>
</swiper>
```

Create a reference to your swiper & You must instantiate swiper on AfterViewInit - your.component.ts

```
@ViewChild('newSwiper') newSwiper: any;

  constructor() {
  }
  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    console.log(this.newSwiper.swiperRef);
    //Swiper instance will be displayed in console
  }
```

Now you can access properties and methods such as slideTo(), slideNext(), slidePrev() and etc.

```
this.newSwiper.swiperRef.slideTo(2, 400);
```

Hope this will be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, adding

```
.swiper-wrapper{
    display:inline-flex;
}
```

works as intended.

Answer (score 1):

make sure you include Swiper CSS styles
and also use encapsulation in @Component

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-sing-accesorios',
  templateUrl: './sing-accesorios.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./sing-accesorios.component.css'],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone having this problem in future - instead of using setTimeout just move the Swiper initialization from OnInit to AfterViewInit, then it works like a charm. Also there's no need to use any 3rd party libraries, as Swiper already natively supports Angular 2+.

Additionally please make sure you include Swiper CSS styles (at minimum core styles or entire bundle if you like).

Answer (score 0):

```
setTimeout(function () {
  const swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
    autoplay: {
      reverseDirection: true,
    },
  });
  const mySwiper = new Swiper(".swiper-container", {
    autoplay: true,
  });
  const swiper1 = new Swiper('.swiper-container2', {
    autoplay: {
      reverseDirection: true,
    },
  });
}, 4000);
```

its works for me

Comment: Code only answers are discouraged. Please provide a summary of how your answer solves the problem and why it may be preferable to the other answers already provided.

Answer (score 0):

This is just an update for Angular ^15.1.0, Swiper ^9.1.0, and Webpack ^5.75.0.

[New Swiper 9.0 reference](https://swiperjs.com/get-started#install-from-npm)

Main entry point is app.component.html

```
<div class="toolbar" role="banner">
  <!-- Navigation -->
</div>

<div class="content" role="main">
  <swiper-slide></swiper-slide>

  <!-- Footer -->
  <footer>

  </footer>

</div>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

and app.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

// import Swiper bundle with all modules installed
import { register } from 'swiper/element/bundle';

// import styles bundle
import 'swiper/css/bundle';
import { SwiperSlideComponent } from './swiper-slide/swiper-slide.component';

// init Swiper:
register();

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    SwiperSlideComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

I created a separate swiper-slide angular component with swiper-slide.component.html

```
<div class="swiper newSwiper">
  <div class="swiper-wrapper">
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 1</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 2</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 3</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 4</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 5</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 6</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 7</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 8</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 9</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

swiper-slide.component.ts - I ran into a problem with emitting the files with Webpack and used [this default trick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59070216/webpack-file-loader-outputs-object-module) to get it running.

For older Webpack version or even without you probably (not tested) need to adjust the @Component like this.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'swiper-slide',
  templateUrl: './swiper-slide.component.html'),
})
```

Ignore the above if u use my initially mentioned dependencies.

```
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import Swiper from 'swiper';

@Component({
  selector: 'swiper-slide',
  template: require('./swiper-slide.component.html').default,
})
export class SwiperSlideComponent {

  @ViewChild('.newSwiper') newSwiper: any;

  constructor() {
  }
  ngOnInit(): void {

    this.newSwiper = new Swiper(".newSwiper", {
      grabCursor: true,
      effect: "creative",
      creativeEffect: {
        prev: {
          shadow: true,
          translate: [ 0, 0, -400 ],
        },
        next: {
          translate: [ "100%", 0, 0 ],
        },
      },
    });
  }

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
  }
}
```

and my global styles.sass (for css add {} and ; accordingly):

```
// Swiper styles for effective slide components
.swiper
  margin: 100px auto
  width: 100%
  height: 500px

.swiper-slide
  display: flex
  align-items: center
  justify-content: center
  font-size: 22px
  font-weight: bold
  color: #fff

.swiper-slide:nth-child(1n)
    background-color: rgb(206, 17, 17)

.swiper-slide:nth-child(2n)
  background-color: rgb(0, 140, 255)

.swiper-slide:nth-child(3n)
  background-color: rgb(10, 184, 111)

.swiper-slide:nth-child(4n)
  background-color: rgb(211, 122, 7)

.swiper-slide:nth-child(5n)
  background-color: rgb(118, 163, 12)

.swiper-slide:nth-child(6n)
  background-color: rgb(180, 10, 47)

.swiper-slide:nth-child(7n)
  background-color: rgb(35, 99, 19)

.swiper-slide:nth-child(8n)
  background-color: rgb(0, 68, 255)

.swiper-slide:nth-child(9n)
  background-color: rgb(218, 12, 218)

.swiper-slide:nth-child(10n)
  background-color: rgb(54, 94, 77)
```

Run your application and enjoy the slider show